# If user belongs to this group, show this, if not, show this

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am a novice to powershell and starting to learn the syntax and what logic is needed, but I have given this a good go.

I need to pop in a conditional field that does the below

- If users are a member of the "Domain Admins" group, then show "Administrator"
- If users are a member of the "ReadOnlyAccess" group, then show "Read Only"

But my script doesn't quite do this and I wandered how my script could be changed to get what I need it to do.

This is my script below:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$OUPath = "OU=1_Users,DC=DGDomain,DC=Local"

$filepath = "C:\temp\users.csv"

$readonlygroup = "ReadOnlyAccess"
$readonlygroupmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $readonlygroup | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName | Select SamAccountName

$admingroup = "Domain Admins"
$admingroupmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $admingroup | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName | Select SamAccountName

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $OUPath |
         Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true } |
         Select SamAccountName

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $OUPath |
Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true } |
Select SamAccountName,
       DisplayName,
       @{Label = "Access Level"
            Expression =  {
                    foreach ($user in $users) {
                        if ($readonlygroupmembers -contains $users)
                            { "Read Only" }
                        else {
                            if ($admingroupmembers -contains $users)
                                { "Administrator" }
                            else
                                { "None" }
                            }
                        } } } |

Export-csv $filepath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: One of the core rules in powershell: If the cmdlet has a filter, there is a reason for that!
I would suggest replacing: Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $OUPath |
Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true } with Get-ADUser -Filter  { Enabled -eq $true } -Properties * -SearchBase $OUPath. 
It should increase performance and decrease resource usage. You may not feel it in small number of objects, but it would increase the performance in larger environments ... and it is regarded as a best practice! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$OUPath = "OU=1_Users,DC=DGDomain,DC=Local"

$filepath = "C:\temp\users.csv"

$readonlygroup = "ReadOnlyAccess"
$readonlygroupmembers = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $readonlygroup | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName).SamAccountName

$admingroup = "Domain Admins"
$admingroupmembers = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $admingroup | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName).SamAccountName

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true } -SearchBase $OUPath -Properties DisplayName

foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($user.SamAccountName -in $admingroupmembers) { $groupMembership = 'DomainAdmin'}
    elseif ($user.SamAccountName -in $readonlygroupmembers) { $groupMembership = 'ReadOnly' }
    else {$groupMembership = 'None'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName = $user.DisplayName
        SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
        AccessLevel = $groupMembership

    }
}

Export-csv $filepath -NoTypeInformation
```